# How to validate the schema structure which is nested json using another class as defined data type

Tags: javascript, schema, mongoose-schema, typegoose

I don't know if this is right way to give define data type.

I also tried using `@mapProp()` annotation.

```
class Temp extends Typegoose {
    @prop({ required: true, _id: false})
    unit!: string;

    @prop({ required: true, _id: false})
    value!: number;
}
class Temp2 extends Typegoose {
    @prop({ required: true,_id: false})
    unit2!: number;

    @prop({ required: true, _id: false})
    value2!: number;

    @prop({ required: true, _id: false})
    option2!: string;

}
class Temp3 extends Typegoose {
    @prop({ required: true, _id: false})
    unit3!: string;
}
export class UserModel extends Typegoose {

    @prop()
    field_type!: string;

    @prop({ _id : false, required: true})
    field_value!: Temp | Temp2 | Temp3;
}
```

I want to get the `field_value` parameters only of these three kind.

If:

```
"field_type" = "temp1"
```

Then:

```
"field_value" = { "unit2":32, "value2":3, "option2": "hello" }
```

Otherwise:

**some error message**

Answer (score 0):

you can do [custom validation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#custom-validators), otherwise try [embedded discriminators](https://thecodebarbarian.com/mongoose-4.12-single-embedded-discriminators) - whatever suits your use-case